# Skipping method visibility results in point-cutting all methods?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, aspect

In AspectJ, if you don't specify the method visibility, are all methods "considered"?

Example:

`pointcut timed() : execution(@Timed !static * (@Metrics).*(..)) && this(object);`

Are all methods (public, private etc.) advised here?

Comment: all are !private !public !protected

Comment: @RamonBoza not possible. so the above aspect would work only for package-private methods? Because it intercepts public ones too